# How to create a Zend Form object dynamically by reading table schema?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I have a project where one of the tables has too many columns (like 80 or more) and setting manually each one in a Zend_Form class became a painful (and prone to errors) work. Is there a way to automatize this by reading the table schema and adding the right elements accordingly to field types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the [describeTable()](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html#zend.db.adapter.list-describe) method in `Zend_Db_Adapter` and create the form elements dynamically based on its results. `describeTable()` returns the data type for each column, so you can create different types of elements according to the column type.

Hope that helps,